# How to know the size of balls printed by mayavi?

Tags: python, 3d, mayavi

I am trying to plot some 3d point cloud with mayavi like so

```
    mlb.figure(bgcolor=(0,0,0))
    mlb.points3d(*my_points[:, 0, :].T, scale_factor=5.0, color=(1,0,0))
    mlb.points3d(*their_points[:, 0, :].T, scale_factor=5.0, color=(0,1,0))
    mlb.show()
```

When playing with scale_factor, the balls which represent each plotted point vary in size.

I would like to know/determine that size.

I have no idea what "5.0" actually means.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [documentation to points3d](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#points3d):

> scale_factor: The scaling applied to the glyphs. the size of the glyph
>   is by default calculated from the inter-glyph spacing. Specify a float
>   to give the maximum glyph size in drawing units

If you add `mlb.axes()` before `mlb.show()` it should make more sense.

You should pass the variable that is used for scaling explicitly as fourth parameter `s` to `points3d(x, y, z, s, ...)`.

We don't know what your `*their_points[:, 0, :].T` does and which shape and dimension it has, but this could for sure mess up the scaling if the wrong dimension is chosen. Try to slice `x, y, z, s` and pass them explicitly.